# How could a 9 hour rainbow be possible?

Tags: light

The BBC article [Taiwan rainbow 'lasts record-breaking nine hours'](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-42219665) also mentions that [Guinness World Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guinness_World_Records) lists six hours as the current record. See also Taiwan News [Taiwan shatters world record for longest-lasting rainbow](https://www.taiwannews.com.tw/en/news/3310942).

Usually rainbows are on the opposite side of the sky from the Sun. We usually see them in the evening or morning.

How can a rainbow be seen for nine or even six hours?

- `Reported rainbow: 06:57 - 15:55,  30-Nov-2017, ~23.1° N (near Taipei, Taiwan)`
- `Official record: ~09:00 - ~15:00, 14-Mar-1994, ~53.9° N (near York, UK)`

Comment: From the pictures it appears the rainbow appears at a spot lower than the observer, so as long as there's a line between the sun, observer, and rainbow, it should be visible as long as there is sun and water drops. I'm thinking it would also help if it's winter, since the sun is closer to the horizon.

Comment: In winter, the sun is low enough in the sky (in northern latitudes) to produce rainbows even at local noon.  Not all that uncommon hereabouts (western US) to see them any time of day.  Given a rainstorm that lasted that long (unlikely here) and moved on the right path, you could have one lasting all day.

Comment: @jamesqf Thanks, the BBC article mentions some details about the weather. Also there are some great images in the second new link I've added.

Comment: waterfalls have them all day, so the weather front would be similar to a waterfall mist in regularity.